# rails modle base search with check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, search

I am working on search functionality in rails and I want a common search method for all the site. For that I am creating a method in app controller with two parameters one is modleName and another one is fieldsArray. but am not able to make it. Please help me.

I want that I set a variable in model that on which columns I need a search as like **(attr_accessible)** and then I need a element which I call in view files and it gets all the columns with labels and check boxes which I set in  model. and I get a result with the specific column name which I enter in search box and which columns I have selected, columns would be multiple selected.

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: So the user decides on which model the search needs to fired ? As you mentioned, you take a ModelName as a param .. right ?

Comment: No I mean I use modelName in search method that on which table I have to find the search results.

Comment: I will pass the modelName where I user that method users will just select the columns and enter the keyword what they want to search.
suppose I use that method in users controller then that method will get all the results from users table and if I use that method in pages then I will pass page model name so that method get records from pages table.

Comment: As far as I understand, you can use `modelName.constantize` to get the model itself(Provided the modelname is correct).
So you could do something like this `params[:modelName].constantize.find("search whatever u want")`
For further reference - http://apidock.com/rails/String/constantize

Comment: How can I create an element based on model search attributes columns which I declare in model so I can use that element any where in my project I just set that attributes in model and pass that element it it create that search form automatically.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by the word "element" here. Can you explain a bit more ?

Comment: element like as helper or common file for searching form I want a common file where I want I get all the labels, check boxes and input text box and get labels and check boxes from model where I set a attribute for search columns.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

Create a utility class which has your generic search method.

```
class Util
  # modelName is a string, fields would be an array of strings, keyword is string as well
  # You could either call fire search from here or from individual models

  def search(modelName, fields, keyword)
    query = ""
    fields.size.each_with_index do |field, index|
      query += "#{field} like #{keyword} "
      query += " OR " if index < fields.size
    end

    modelName.constantize.where(query)
    # Or create search method in all ur models which you want to search and 
    modelName.constantize.search(fields, keyword)

   end
 end
```

I haven't included the model search methods as its self explanatory as to what the method should look like.

Let me know if this helps

Comment: this is controller its good but I want common view file with fileds which I define in model search able attributes please let me know how can I do this.? it will help me a lot..

Comment: Its difficult to understand your question, its unclear from the question as to what you want. Can you come over to chat please.